# Transforming included configuration files using configSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-config, web-config-transform

This question is kind of a two parter. In VS2015 my MVC project has multiple different build configurations, Test, UAT, Live etc. With my `web.config` I can simply right click it and select **Add Config Transform** to create the transform files for each build configuration.

If I have an external config file, such as `Log4Net.config` how can I configure this to have dependant transforms like `web.config` ? Is this done manually by editing the `project.csproj` file ?

Secondly, I have a `web.config` file thus :

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, Log4net" />
    </configSections>

    ...

    <log4net configSource="Log4Net.config" />
</configuration>
```

When I build the project, the `web.config` automatically gets transformed through the following AfterBuild target in the `project.csproj` file :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config"
            Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config"
            Destination="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).config" />
</Target>
```

How can I transform the included `Log4Net.config` file using the same configuration transformation ? I realise that I could place another `TransformXml` into the AfterBuild target, but is this the correct way of doing this transform, or am I missing something ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @MatiasCicero I've solved it using an additional TransformXml in the AfterBuild target. I've outlined it in the answer below. HTH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I opted for the solution of using a base `Log4Net.config` file, a `Log4Net.XXX.config` file for each build configuration and an additional `TransformXml` task in the `AfterBuild` target :

- Log4Net.config
- Log4Net.Debug.config
- Log4Net.Release.config
- Log4Net.Test.config
- Log4Net.UAT.config

The `project.csproj` file now looks like this :

```
<Content Include="Log4Net.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<None Include="Log4Net.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>Log4Net.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Log4Net.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>Log4Net.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Log4Net.Test.config">
  <DependentUpon>Log4Net.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Log4Net.UAT.config">
  <DependentUpon>Log4Net.config</DependentUpon>
</None>

....

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).config" />
   <TransformXml Source="Log4Net.config" Transform="Log4Net.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(OutputPath)\Log4Net.config" />
</Target>
```

And an example `Log4Net.Test.config` looks like this (I am using the transform to change connection strings and Log4Net's logging level) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<log4net  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <appender>
        <connectionString
            value="Data Source=example.com;Initial Catalog=ExampleLogs;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"
            xdt:Transform="Replace" />
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level
            value="DEBUG"
            xdt:Transform="Replace" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

This transforms the `Log4Net.config` file in the output path successfully. It uses the same approach as transforming `web.config` files and so should be easily understandable by any other developer that picks up the project.

Whilst this works and has been in production for a while now, I'm still looking for some confirmation that this is the correct way of doing transforms of included config files.