# Disable database publish in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publishing, webdeploy, publish-profiles

I need to disable the database publish section inside publishing profile. I know this may be done somewhere inside `<PublishDatabaseSettings>` element but I don't know how it can be done. There is a thread like this [VS2015 pubxml: how to exclude or eliminate the <PublishDatabaseSettings> section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340292/vs2015-pubxml-how-to-exclude-or-eliminate-the-publishdatabasesettings-section) but it has no answers; the only difference being I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Is it something which cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit .csproj file using a text editor and disable publishing databases by changing the property value of "PublishDatabases" to false

```
<PublishDatabases>false</PublishDatabases>
```